# Concatenate columns, only keeping the separator if multiple values exist (non-NA values)

Tags: r, dataframe, concatenation, na, separator

Does anyone know of a method in R to concatenate n columns but only keep the separator if there is a value in that row? If you run the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(
                  name1 = c("Jim","Bob","Sue"),
                  name2 = c("Jane","","Bane"),
                  name3 = c('Conor',"",""),
                  name4 = c("","","Bonor")
                )

df$names <- paste(df$name1,df$name2,df$name3, sep=";")
```

You will see that separators are included at the end and in-between values even though the cells are empty, with the output:

```
df =

name1 name2 name3 name4  names
Jim   Jane  Conor        Jim;Jane;Conor;
Bob                      Bob;;;
Sue   Bane        Bonor  Sue;Bane;;Bonor
```

Is there any method to either not include or drop separators in the case where the cells are empty? With the desired outcome:

```
df =

name1 name2 name3 name4  names
Jim   Jane  Conor        Jim;Jane;Conor
Bob                      Bob
Sue   Bane        Bonor  Sue;Bane;Bonor
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(na_if,"") %>% 
  unite("names", everything(), sep = ";", remove = F, na.rm = T)

#>            names name1 name2 name3 name4
#> 1 Jim;Jane;Conor   Jim  Jane Conor  <NA>
#> 2            Bob   Bob  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
#> 3 Sue;Bane;Bonor   Sue  Bane  <NA> Bonor
```

##### Update: applying this solution on specific columns.

I am modifying akrun's answer from the comment below;

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(c("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4"), na_if, "", 
                .names = "{.col}_changed")) %>% 
  unite(names, ends_with('_changed'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ";")

#>   name1 name2 name3 name4          names
#> 1   Jim  Jane Conor       Jim;Jane;Conor
#> 2   Bob                              Bob
#> 3   Sue  Bane       Bonor Sue;Bane;Bonor
```

Comment: If you don't want to change the original values `df %>% mutate(across(starts_with('name'), na_if, "", .names = "{.col}_changed")) %>% unite(names, ends_with('changed'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ";")`

Comment: These are both great, thanks! May I ask what the difference is?

Comment: @JohnConor akrun's answer does not alter (replacing blank cells with NA) the original columns since we are mutating "helper" columns. It also preserves the order that you showed in your desired output (name1 to name4 comes first, and the concatenated column is at the end).

Comment: Thank you @M--! One other thing I realized is that in my real dataset I actually need to pass the names, or at least position, of the columns as it has ~200 columns and I only need to concatenate 5 of them. Is there an easy way to amend the method to do this? I can update in the original question if that would help.